# ElasticSearch - Searching record with exact value from array field

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, spring-data-elasticsearch

I've been struggling for days on how to achieve this.

[image]

from the image above. I'm trying to retrieve data which ONLY contains **101325** under **contributeuserids** field which is an array.

So for the records that contains other values such as **101325** should not be returned even if they contain 101325.

in java I'm using query builder. But would like to know how to come up with a query on this.

Thanks for the help

Updated.

tried this below but getting an error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LG9Bn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well, this work if you dont have duplicate key 101325 inside the same array, but you could easily modify script if needed ;).
Care with the ' ' inside the script.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "source": "doc.containsKey('contributeuserids') && doc['contributeuserids'].length == 1",
            "lang": "painless"
          }
        }
      },
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "contributeuserids": [
              "101325"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: tried that but getting an error

Comment: Could you share the error? + your es version plrease.

Comment: I updated the post.. attaching the screenshot

Comment: {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "source": "doc['contributeuserids.keyword'].length == 1",
            "lang": "painless"
          }
        }
      },
   "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "contributeuserids": [
              "101325"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}